mongodb realm js collection.watch() fails with [AbortError: Aborted]
I am developing react native app with mongodb.
I am using realm node sdk 12.13.1.
React native version is 0.75.4.
Can anyone teach me what is the problem?
My current code is as follows.
try {
  var db = await MongoEngine.getDB();
  var collection = db.collection("Notification");

  var changeStream = collection.watch();
  for await (var change of changeStream) {

    this.changeListeners.forEach(listener => {
      try {
        listener.callback();
      } catch(error) {
        console.error("error: ", error.message);
      }
    });
  }
  
} catch(error) {
  console.error("error: ", error);
}

Here the MongoEngine.getDB() just do connect to mongdo atlas service app.
When called this, the error does not occur but after some time( about few mins) this function failed with [AbortError: Aborted]

When using change streams in MongoDB, the connection may get aborted after a period of inactivity. This is typically due to the database or network configuration closing idle connections to save resources.
Potential solutions include: automatic reconnection and updating configurations to keep idle connections for longer period.
async function watchCollection() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const db = await MongoEngine.getDB();
      const collection = db.collection("Notification");
      const changeStream = collection.watch([], { maxAwaitTimeMS: 60000 });

      for await (const change of changeStream) {
        this.changeListeners.forEach(listener => {
          try {
            listener.callback();
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Callback error: ", error.message);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Stream error: ", error.message);
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // Retry delay
    }
  }
}

Another option:
Set maxAwaitTimeMS when calling watch() to specify the maximum time in milliseconds that the server waits for new changes before it returns an empty result. It helps keep the connection active

Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it does not work for me.
